# Setting proxy username and password for Android setRecommendedGlobalProxy

Tags: android, proxy, device-policy-manager

I'm trying to set a network independent proxy server to an android device using [setRecommendedGlobalProxy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setRecommendedGlobalProxy(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.net.ProxyInfo)) method.

```
ProxyInfo proxyInfo = ProxyInfo.buildDirectProxy(hostname, port);
devicePolicyManager.setRecommendedGlobalProxy(deviceAdmin, proxyInfo);
```

This works when the proxy server doesn't have any authentication. How should I set the credentials to the `ProxyInfo` object when there are a username and a password.

I tried setting the hostname as `username:password@proxyserverhost.com` but seems the device does not pick up the proxy settings. I can see the following error in the log cat.

```
1666-5220/? D/ConnectivityService: Invalid proxy properties, ignoring: [test:abc123@10.0.0.6] 3128
```